# Combine Checkbox value with Selection Option value in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a form that has a list of checkboxes and selection option.  It's basically an order form.  When a customer clicks on a checkbox I'd like the value of the Select Option as well as the Checkbox's value to be sent with the form.

I really don't know AJAX.  I'm using a script I found to get all the data to a php file.  What do I need to add to the jquery to make the option and checkbox value of all the checked items combine as one variable?

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
           <select class="qty" name="qty" id="qty">
             <option value="1">1</option>
           </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>       
        <input id="Part1_1" name="Part[]" type="checkbox" value="Part 1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
           <select class="qty" name="qty" id="qty1">
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
           </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>       
        <input id="Part1_2" name="Part[]" type="checkbox" value="Part 2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact-form").on("submit",function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
          var sendData = $( this ).serialize();
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "orderform.php",
              data: sendData,
              success: function(data){
                  $(".response_msg").text(data);
                  $(".response_msg").slideDown();                     
              }           
          });

    });
    });
    </script>
```

EDIT:
I'd like to pass along to the php a variable for each part.  So if Part 1 is checked then the value of the checkbox and the value of the quantity will be grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FormData object which would allow you to append the value of the ComboBox and Select list and send that in an ajax request.

Check this [FormData](http://www.javascripture.com/FormData)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `select` value this way. And you should also add the new parameter in your method on the server. In the example I named it as `select_param`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact-form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sendData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "orderform.php",
            data: sendData + "&select_param1=" + $("#qty option:selected").text() + 
                             "&select_param2=" + $("#qty1 option:selected").text(),
            success: function(data) {
                $(".response_msg").text(data);
                $(".response_msg").slideDown();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: To get the select_param info in the php I'd use: $_POST['select_param'] ?  How would this parameter work to group Part 1's quantity with Part 1 and if Part 2 is selected then Part 2's quantity would be grouped with that?  I updated my question to show what I mean.

Comment: You can get the values with jQuery that will work. To add more parameters, just add the parameters you want.

Comment: In this new case you commented would be: `data: sendData + "&select_param1=" + $("#qty option:selected").text() + "&select_param2=" + $("#qty1 option:selected").text(),`. 
I changed the answer